# MySQL server has gone away, PDO and max_allowed_packet in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, max-allowed-packet

Do you know how to avoid the following fatal error message :

> "...MySQL server has gone away".

I suppose this means that PDO connection to MySQL has been lost.

I have checked `MySQL max_allowed_packet` variable which is equal to **268435456** (I think this value is more than enough).

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your respective answers. After few days of investigations, I decided to reset PDO MySQL connection every 250 seconds. I know it is not the best in class solution but it is at least a solution to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "avoid" this error. This error happens when you lose connection to the DB server. This can happen for a variety of reasons. The most common reason for the `MySQL server has gone away` error, is that the server timed out and closed the connection.

Some other common reasons are:

- You (or the db administrator) has killed the running thread.
- You tried to run a query after closing the connection to the server.
- You got a timeout from the TCP/IP connection on the client side.
- You have encountered a timeout on the server side and the automatic reconnection in the client is disabled.
- And more.

Check out this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) from the MYSQL docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the max_connections and make sure they aren´t reached - that´s the most common cause I remember for you to get this error.